# Get a submitted value with AJAX (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this code in my view

```
<form>
<%= form_tag(portefeuillemodele_path, :remote => true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:date, "The selected date is:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:date) %>

  <%= submit_tag("OK") %>
<% end %>
</form>
```

And this in my controller

```
  def index
    @portefeuillemodeles = Portefeuillemodele.all
    @date = params[:date]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @portefeuillemodeles }
    end
  end
```

When I press the submit button, it doesn't do anything.
And I have ajax gem installed, what do I need to just save the submitted value , so I can use it in my view ?

Comment: Remove the `form` tags wrapped outside of `form_tag` helper block.  You shouldn't be nesting form tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code

```
<form> // you don't need this tag form_tag will create those tags for you
  <%= form_tag(portefeuillemodele_path, :remote => true) do %>
    <%= label_tag(:date, "The selected date is:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:date) %>

    <%= submit_tag %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

Secondly when you are using ajax you need js format in your controller

```
def index
  @portefeuillemodeles = Portefeuillemodele.all
  @date = params[:date] # this will give you access to your date but you need to check your params to be sure

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.js{} # ajax will call this format not html or json
    format.json { render json: @portefeuillemodeles }
  end
end
```

*This will allow rails to look for a file named **index.js.erb** where you can manipulate your DOM elements by js*. For details refer to [**`Working with Javascript in Rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)

Comment: if you can post your params from terminal then we can replace params[:date] accordingly which will allow you to access your date field inside your method

Comment: is it the same if I want to manipulate params[:date] in a spectific partial (in the same layout of course) ?

Comment: @Ananas had a typo with rails will look for `index.js.erb` not html.erb and sorry didn't get your question. You will have access to @date in your index.js.erb file and then you can just render your partial passing your @date as locals

Comment: I posted a new Question, more specific : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627818/ajax-and-ruby-on-rails-with-local-variable.