# Ajax and Ruby on Rails with local variable?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I really don't get how to use Ajax with Ruby on Rails. I must be missing something simple.

What I want to do is to ask the user to select a date, and then make a table of documents appear, but only with the selected date (Date is an attribute of Document).

My idea is to create a local variable witch is not in my database, store the selected date in it, and then create a loop in my view saying for example @document.where(:date = date).each...

In **app/controllers/documents_controller.rb**, I have :

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController

 def information
    @documents = Document.all
    @date = params[:date]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js{}
      format.json { render json: @documents}
    end
  end

end
```

And in **app/views/documents/_information.js.erb**, I have:

```
<%= form_tag(document, :remote => true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:date, "The selected date is:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:date) %>

  <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

In the end, I have a field where the user puts his date, but the submit button doesn't do anything.
What do I miss ?

Comment: add a onchange event using jQuery on the text_field which send a ajax request with the selected date. In the method where the ajax is received, collect all the documents related to the date. In the js.erb file, replace a html element on the current page with a partial which iterates over the documents. Ajax isnt hard.

Comment: would you mind showing how i should implement the onchange event and the js.erb file ?

Comment: @Ananas field where you are selecting your date is in a form? and your partial should be _information.html.erb not js.erb

Comment: Yes my partial is _information.html.erb, and the field where I select my data is in this very partial.

Comment: @Ananas what is the problem you are facing? In your previous question also i explained details of using ajax

Comment: I did everything you said but I still can't use ajax correctly. In fact, I didn't understand the part where you talked about the js.erb file. What should I put in it ? And should I put my form_tag (where the user chooses a date) in a different file or can I let it in _information.html.erb ?

Comment: @Ananas about the date field, it entirely depends on your work flow. You can either use jquery on change to call your ajax or you can use a form_tag. Are you showing just an input field to the user or there are any other fields in form too?

Comment: @Mandeep Yes I'm showing just an input field to the user. And then I want to save what he writes in order let's say to simply print it in my view _information.html.erb. Where should I put the form_tag, is my code in the controller correct, and do I have to add something elsewhere ?

Comment: @Ananas click on the chat link in my previous comment and lets solve your issue :)

Comment: @Mandeep, I need 3 reputation points :/. Vote for the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed you need to change the flow of your app.Lets go through steps one by one

a. create your input field where you are selecting your date field. You already have your form for that

```
<%= form_tag(you_path_for_information_method, :remote => true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:date, "The selected date is:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:date) %>
  <%= label_tag(:portfolio, "Add portfolio") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:portfolio) %>
  <%= submit_tag %>

<% end %>
```

In controller

```
def information
  @documents = Document.all
  @date = params[:date]
  @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
  end
end
```

In your information.js.erb you can have:

```
$("#some_id_of_parent").html("<%=j render partial: "your_partial", locals: {portfolio: @portfolio} %>")
```